# Should I delete asker background/experience?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I'm tempted to delete the first paragraph of this question:

[Structuring multiple pages within DOM for JavaScript web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367046/javascript-web-app-with-mutiple-pages-in-dom)

> I'm about to dive in head first to creating a Javascript web app. I'm not a Javascript novice, I know my way around, this is just a best practice question. I have done some research on the topic and just wanted to hear what SO had.

The answer to this question does not depend on the user's background. It's just some irrelevant stuff to read before the real question begins.

Acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the dup. Searching from my phone wasn't the most productive way to look for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions should be as succinct as possible. I will typically remove any extraneous information including signatures, salutations and off-topic chit-chat. Anything not actually important to answering the question is wasting the readers' time.

Comment: Agreed. In this case I think the user's ego just wants us to know he's not a novice. But who cares?