# Is it good to suggest a simplified, summarized edit on a long-winded question?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

**Note:** [Is it OK to edit and cut down an overly verbose question to try and make it a more “canonical” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214945/is-it-ok-to-edit-and-cut-down-an-overly-verbose-question-to-try-and-make-it-a-mo) and all of its answers are specifically geared toward a very bad example of this concept.

*That title should be:*

> **Is it ok to take a big question, remove important details, and condense it to 2 lines?**

The answers provided there do not answer this question.

---

I think of Stack Exchange as a place for good questions to be collected which can each potentially benefit the masses in the future.

However, people don't usually think:

> How can I ask this in a way that will optimize value for future Google searchers?

More often, it's more to the effect of:

> I'm confused please help me

OR

> I don't really know the right question to ask, but here's my problem.

Both are OK if the asker has an original genuine problem, but I feel like in many of these situations I could generalize the question, removing details that aren't relevant, and summarizing long situation explanations into the details that matter.

**Is it beneficial to Stack Exchange for users to suggest a condensed, (*appropriately) summarized, simplified edit to questions that are a bit long-winded?**

*Summaries should never change the meaning of the OP nor add the editor's own taste or opinion.

---

To clarify what I mean, here is an example:

### [How can I correct an elder team member without causing offence?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27840/how-can-i-correct-an-elder-team-member-without-causing-offence)

> I am working for a Consulting firm and they employed me at their
>   client location for their client project. My team consists of
>   different team member who are also employed from different
>   organizations who are vendors to my current client. After joining few
>   months because of my good work my client manager promoted me a lead
>   for my fellow developers.
>
> I am now getting some hard time with one of my time member. Below are
>   some facts and
>
> - He is elder than me in age. He looks aged and with grey hair.  I look younger than my age with my physic. It is always a hesitation and
>     a sense of fear in me that my actions may offend him.
> - While requirement analysis phase he doesn’t use the time properly and don’t do thorough analysis instead do superficial analysis and
>     says that I didn’t see any issue probably I might see issues further.
>     I will inform you when I see any issue with requirement and if I need
>     any further inputs
> - And  his status and time lines in the scrum also not so clear and more generic or vague. In order to get time lines for a given task I
>     have to send at least 3 reminder mails to him. After 3 mails I will
>     get very vague time lines like “task1 takes probably 2 weeks. may less
>     or more. I will inform you later. Other tasks depend on task1 I will
>     give estimates once I am done with task1”. His status on the scrum
>     also very vague. “ I am started working on task1. It is in progress
>     and it may take may be this week end or it may extend”. It is not
>     clear when he is planning to do etc..
> - His development also not so inline. After having so many requirement review, architecture design and explanation sessions, he
>     started development with worst design which is completely against our
>     basic design principles. when I propose required design he bluntly
>     disagrees and says rudely it is totally wrong. Then I have setup
>     meeting with senior architect about this and then he explains and
>     suggested to go with my design.
> - While developing he develops with different pattern which deviates the as per the agreed upon design and structure. He is doing same
>     mistake again and again.  I tried to correct each and every time and
>     he started feeling offending. He started saying comments like “Do I
>     need to talk and take step by step instructions each and every time
>     when I code? is it the process that you want me to follow?”
>
> Now how can I correct him gracefully with out make him offend?
>
> I might have done some mistakes in the process of correcting him or
>   leading him on right direction, Now I am not more interested in
>   knowing those mistakes. Now I am more interested in what has to be
>   done to correct the situation and gracefully correct him to wards
>   right path.

**Simplified, summarized, and condensed to:**

> I am working for a consulting firm and they employed me at their
>   client location for their client project. My team consists of
>   different team members who are also employed from different
>   organizations who are vendors to my current client. After joining a
>   few months my client manager promoted me a team lead position.
>
> I am now having trouble with one of my team members. Below are some
>   facts:
>
> - He is elder to me. I always hesitate interacting with him fearing that my actions may offend him.
> - In the requirements analysis phase he misuses his time and doesn't perform to my expectations.
> - I have to repeatedly send him my requests to get a response.
> - His development practices do not meet my expectations nor the agreed upon structure. His practices actively defy our development
>     principles. He responds negatively toward being reprehended for this
>     poor performance.
> - He makes the same mistake again and again and gets offended when corrected. He has commented to the effect of: “Do I need to talk and
>     take step by step instructions each and every time when I code? Is
>     that the process that you want me to follow?”
>
> How can I correct him gracefully without making him feel offended?

***Note:*** *Regardless of whether or not you fully agree with every word in this example, please focus your answer on the practice in general, and not this specific case. It is meant to be used as an example rather than as the topic of the question.*

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/aggressive-edits

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135619/is-it-correct-to-edit-a-question-to-remove-a-verbose-introduction http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138938/should-i-delete-asker-background-experience http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149019/what-is-the-preffered-approach-regarding-im-new-to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171083/is-there-such-thing-as-too-much-detail-in-question

Comment: With the master question you should focus on the practise in general, and not the specific case. The practise where you can trim the excess for a more focussed question. Don't get hung up on that specific case being down to two sentences.

Comment: [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214951/260776) on the master question you mark as duplicate is general, but it doesn't really give any answer. It sort of just offers general advice on editing. There's no definitive answer given. @random

Comment: how does the accepted answer there not answer your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate. Shog9's answer answers your question. I'm not sure what you mean by "more definitive." His answer is very firm and clear. Would you prefer a one word YES or NO? You won't find that here. If you want more discussion on the topic? See the chats. You've already linked to an answer that answers your question by a question of the same title, and IMO it's pretty important to point out when NOT to do this as well, which makes your question even *more* related.

Comment: That's absurd. You will have to think for yourself and use good judgment, and meta will not obviate that.